# Trying to find a way to load xml with ajax on a link click

Tags: html, xml, ajax

What I'm trying to find a way to do is load some data from xml, and load it on a page dynamically with a click on a link. Is this possible? Is there anyway someone can point me in the right direction? Is it possible to make a link call a javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this easily, you could use jQuery. It will auto-detect XML, but you can also force it:

```
$('#link').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'yourXMLfile.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {
      $(data).find('xmltag').each(function(i,el){
        alert( $(this).text() );
      });
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

The code above will alert all text of all `<xmltag>` tags

Comment: How do you call the function on the link? I figured it would work like this..    <a href="#" id="myLink">Text to Click</a> then I edited your code $('myLink').click(function(){

Comment: Doesn't look like it.. I threw an alert in at the start of it and it doesn't seem to be getting reached.

Comment: This is what I have                      $('#myLink').click(function(){

  $.ajax({
    url: 'news.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {
    alert('reached');
      $(data).find('newsone').each(function(i,el){
        alert( $(this).text() );
      });
    }
  });

  return false;
});

</script>                                                                  I could have done something wrong though, I'm kind of new to jquery.

Comment: Have you wrapped it in an onready event? `$(document).ready(function(){ [code] });`. That executes the code when the DOM is ready

Comment: No but, I just tried wrapping all the code around that and it didn't seem to do anything. Would you mind showing me how that would look? I may have done it wrong.

Comment: I have something better, a tutorial which covers everything: http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/